# Spring boot @Cron taking a long time(5 min) to start up

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cron

have a cron job class which is annotated with @Component.
when I am running the cron job its taking approx 5 min to start up.
the last logs are mentioned above

```
eligible.coupon.merchant.scheduler.cron=0 * * * * *
```

```
Sep 21, 2020 2:59:43 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
Sep 21, 2020 2:59:43 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Sep 21, 2020 2:59:43 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Sep 21, 2020 2:59:44 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
Sep 21, 2020 2:59:45 PM org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry register
INFO: HHH000270: Type registration [byte[]] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.BinaryType@1410d645
Sep 21, 2020 2:59:45 PM org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry register
INFO: HHH000270: Type registration [[B] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.BinaryType@1410d645
Sep 21, 2020 2:59:45 PM org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry register
INFO: HHH000270: Type registration [Byte[]] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.WrapperBinaryType@13908f9c
Sep 21, 2020 2:59:45 PM org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry register
```

```
@Component
public class EligibleMerchantController extends DigitalApiRestServiceBinding implements MerchantSchedulerService {

    protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EligibleMerchantController.class);

    @Value("${eligible.coupon.merchant.pagesize}")
    Integer defaultPagesize;

    @Autowired
    EligibleMerchantBusinessService service;

    @Override
    @Scheduled(cron = "${eligible.coupon.merchant.scheduler.cron}")
    public void eligibleMerchantScheduler() {

       // my cron job
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        return new ConcurrentTaskScheduler();
    }
}
```

its taking more than 5 min which it shouldnt

Comment: What is the actual CRON expression?  Are you sure that your Java/machine server time is correct and off by some number of minutes?

Comment: using this expression

Comment: eligible.coupon.merchant.scheduler.cron=0 * * * * *

Comment: The task will take however long it takes for all init and autowiring to happen.  5 minutes sounds like a long time, but seems possible.

Comment: Please don't place `@Bean` methods in `@Component`. Nor is it the scheduling that takes so long, your application takes it time to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed a property

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`

this was taking a long time

Comment: Then, if I want how it would be updating the schema?